# How to access sql server from Android the clean way?

Tags: php, android, sql-server, jsoup

On my project, I'm using a php site for getting data from sql server.

My android app connect the php site and send values , php site take values with POST method, and get the intended values from sql, after that, write in a html div(has an id), and last my app get data from html div with jsoup parser.

This way is working correctly, I'll ask about performance, when I Googled I saw a library called jdbc, so if I connect my app directly to sql server, is it get less loading time, or my way is true?

Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Why are you returning the result in a div of a html page? You could better return only the result. So no jsoup parsing needed.

Comment: Now, php return only one result. But next I have to return multiple results, and I have to parse them. So I have to use html div, and parse it. Isn't it? Or there is an easier method?

Comment: Do not use html and divs. Just return your result(s). You should be able to return them in such a way that your Android code can separate them easy. Looks very simple to me.

Comment: But it is unclear what you mean with 'i have to parse them'. If jsoup has parsed a result from a div then do you have to parse that result too? I think so. But you could inform us better.

Comment: I use Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(URL).get(); Elements info = doc.select("div#DivName"); and save info.text() in a string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> when I Googled I saw a library called jdbc, so if I connect my app directly to sql server

You can connect your app to sql server as long as sql server is accessible from Internet or your app has access to a network where sql server is accessible.

> is it get less loading time

You can expect far better response time because you won't need the php site anymore as long as your JDBC code is well written.